# Apex map<ID,SObject> initialization - compiler 'Unexpected Error'

Tags: apex

This is more of a placeholder note for others who might stumble upon this apparent error in the Apex Compiler while coding a `map <id,sobject>` initialization using dynamic SOQL (such as when list of fields is dynamic).

**Incorrect syntax - compiler blows up**

```
map<ID,Account> res = 
   new Map<ID,Account> ((Account) Database.query('select id from Account'));
```

or (an even worse beginner mistake)

```
map<ID,Account> res = new Map<ID,Account> ('select id from Account');
```

> An unexpected error has occurred. 2137292630-263233
>   (1873312459) for deploymentId=1drq0000000xEN2AAM If this persists,
>   please contact customer support.

*In Developer Console, above error message is preceded by 'Deployment Error"*

**The correct syntax (compiles fine)**

```
map<ID,Account> res = 
            new Map<ID,Account> ((List<Account>) Database.query('select id from Account'));
```

The map initialization is expecting a list of SObjects of the proper type. Compiler error noted at V35. I looked in Known Issues and find it hard to believe I'm the first to see this.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a query result from dynamic apex as a single account

```
Account a = (Account) Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1');
```

---

You will of course get a run-time error if there is more than 1 account returned from the query

```
Account a2 = (Account) Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 2');
```

> FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

---

The error you were seeing occurs when attempting to construct a map with a single record or a set rather than using a list or map. [Map Constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_constructors)

```
Account a3 = new Account();
map<Id,Account> ma = new map<Id,Account>(a3);
```

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1782200980-45844 (1670008057)

(This was run as Anonymous Apex, so the error message doesn't reference a deployment.)

Comment: yes, thank you for adding to the KB here at SFSE-- I was (apparently unsuccessfully) trying to make the point that the Apex compiler was blowing up when it shouldn't -- using the correct syntax works fine as you note; using the incorrect syntax should generate a meaningful compiler error message

Comment: @crop1645 Understood. I just wanted to clarify that the error was unrelated to deployment and dynamic SOQL.

Comment: excellent; I did my compile in DC and got 'Deployment Error'  ; I'll change the title in the OP